# How to remove messageLabel from tab order in JFace's TitleAreaDialog

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I'm looking for a way to remove the `messageLabel` (emphasized with a red arrow in the image) from the tab order in a class which extends `TitleAreaDialog`. The workaround currently looks like this:

```
getButton(IDialogConstants.CANCEL_ID).addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener() {
  @Override
  public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent e) {
    if (e.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_NEXT) {
      e.doit = false;
      textUsername.forceFocus();
    }
  }
});
```

My current workaround is to listen for a `TraverseEvent` in the upper- and lowermost composites and manually force focus to the correct composite.

However, I'm searching for a more general solution, which could be implemented in a `CommonTitleAreaDialog` class, for every instance in our product.

[image]

Comment: What exactly keeps you from using the traverse-listener workaround in a general solution?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann Having to put a listener onto the composites surrounding the `messageLabel` (see edit for code sample). What (more specifically) were you thinking about when using a traverse-listener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two possible ways to generalize your approach.

1. You can try to manipulate the tab order of the parent of the title image label, which has the same parent as the message label

   ```java
   getTitleImageLabel().getParent().setTabList( new Control[ 0 ] );
   ```
2. Or you can add a `TraverseListener` to the last button of the button bar (`getButtonBar()`) that changes tab traversal and jumps to the first focusable control. To find the first control, you may hook into `createDialogArea()` and start searching for the right control from the control it returns.
   Something along these lines:

   ```java
   @Override
   protected Control createDialogArea( Composite parent ) {
     Control startPoint = super.createDialogArea( parent );
     Control firstControl = null;
     if( startPoint instanceof Composite ) {
       Composite composite = ( Composite )startPoint;
       Control[] children = composite.getChildren();
       for( Control control : children ) {
         if( ( control.getStyle() & SWT.NO_FOCUS ) == 0 ) {
           firstControl = control;
           break;
         }
       }
     }
     return parent;
   }
   ```

   Probably, the code needs to be changed to recursively search for the first suitable control.

Both require to extend `TitleAreaDialog` and, to a certain extent, rely on the implementation details of this class. For example, if the title image label is given an extra parent, then `setTabList()` would operate on the wrong composite.